# How to upload image to eclipse so i can load it

Tags: java, eclipse, image

Okay, I'm using code from a book about Java, which displays 4 PNG's and 1 JPG under some text. They provide me with code and the images are downloadable from the site, which i downloaded. To upload the images to eclipse, I made a source folder in my project to keep the images. I then uploaded my images to the "images" source folder by doing New>File>2DGraphicsTest>LinkToFileSystem> and then i selected my image. But for some reason, when i run the following code i just get the text that goes above my pictures....

My question is, how do i upload the images properly so that the loadImage(image) thing gets it?
Code:

```
import java.awt.*;
```

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ImageTest extends JFrame {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    DisplayMode displayMode;

    if (args.length == 3) {
        displayMode = new DisplayMode(
            Integer.parseInt(args[0]),
            Integer.parseInt(args[1]),
            Integer.parseInt(args[2]),
            DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN);
    }
    else {
        displayMode = new DisplayMode(800, 600, 16,
            DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN);
    }

    ImageTest test = new ImageTest();
    test.run(displayMode);
}

private static final int FONT_SIZE = 24;
private static final long DEMO_TIME = 10000;

private SimpleScreenManager screen;
private Image bgImage;
private Image opaqueImage;
private Image transparentImage;
private Image translucentImage;
private Image antiAliasedImage;
private boolean imagesLoaded;

public void run(DisplayMode displayMode) {
    setBackground(Color.blue);
    setForeground(Color.black);
    setFont(new Font("Consolas", Font.PLAIN, FONT_SIZE));
    imagesLoaded = false;

    screen = new SimpleScreenManager();
    try {
        screen.setFullScreen(displayMode, this);
        loadImages();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(DEMO_TIME);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex) { }
    }
    finally {
        screen.restoreScreen();
    }
}


public void loadImages() {
    bgImage = loadImage("images/background.jpg");
    opaqueImage = loadImage("images/opaque.png");
    transparentImage = loadImage("images/transparent.png");
    translucentImage = loadImage("images/translucent.png");
    antiAliasedImage = loadImage("images/antialiased.png");
    imagesLoaded = true;
    // signal to AWT to repaint this window
    repaint();
}


private Image loadImage(String fileName) {
    return new ImageIcon(fileName).getImage();
}


public void paint(Graphics g) {
    // set text anti-aliasing
    if (g instanceof Graphics2D) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(
            RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    }

    // draw images
    if (imagesLoaded) {
        g.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0, null);
        drawImage(g, opaqueImage, 0, 0, "Opaque");
        drawImage(g, transparentImage, 320, 0, "Transparent");
        drawImage(g, translucentImage, 0, 300, "Translucent");
        drawImage(g, antiAliasedImage, 320, 300,
            "Translucent (Anti-Aliased)");
    }
    else {
        g.drawString("Loading Images...", 5, FONT_SIZE);
    }
}


public void drawImage(Graphics g, Image image, int x, int y,
    String caption)
{
    g.drawImage(image, x, y, null);
    g.drawString(caption, x + 5, y + FONT_SIZE +
        image.getHeight(null));
}
```

}

Comment: It's difficult to tell from your description, but if the images are stored within the `src` directory or Eclipses runtime classpath, then you may need to use `ImageIcon(URL)` and `Class#getResource` to load the images

Comment: @MadProgrammer its stored in a source folder called "images," but thankz. Also, I'm sure it's not a problem with the code because I am using source code from a book.

Comment: Try using something more like `return new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/" + name)).getImage();`

Comment: @MadProgrammer it isn't a code problem but i will try

Comment: `ImageIcon(String)` expects the specified resource to be a file on the file system, by placing the images within the `src` directory, you've embedded them within the application context, meaning that they can no longer be referenced as normal files, but need to be loaded via the `Classloader` resource management APIs...

Comment: @MadProgrammer In the 3rd comment here, what do i replace "/" and "name" with? I'm gana try that :L

Comment: It's the same call you did in your `loadImage` method, expect I prefixed it with a `/` otherwise the lookup would be relative to the class trying to load the resource...`new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/transparent.png")).getImage()`

Comment: You might also want to look at [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Derpz...didn't work ;-; i cry in my pillowz

Comment: @MadProgrammer Now, I'm very sure it's because of the way i uploaded it. I'm using eclipse. The way i did it was that i made a source folder and dumped images in there, is that correct?

Comment: Not a user of Eclipse (get more question about it than any other IDE though) - I was under the impression if the images existed within the `src` directory of the project, they should be automatically embedded.  If you have "another" directory, they Java/Eclipse may not be able to find them...

Comment: OMG, i just saw a question EXACTLY like mine :O Illuminati confirmed???

Comment: @MadProgrammer so..i have to put the images in src? k den

Comment: No idea.  *"i made a source folder"* doesn't sound like it, as an Eclipse project should already have a source directory...

Comment: @MadProgrammer i made a new one for my images

Comment: Try putting the images in the original...

Comment: Well, that's a relief...